# django-decouple throws an error whenever it encounters '.'

Tags: python, django

django-decouple throws an error

```
'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit' 
module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

whenever it encounters '.' e.g django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend, smtp.gmail.com

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

I think `dotted_path` is not a string, it's a tuple as said in the error message. you probably need to do something like `dotted_path[0].rsplit('.', 1)`